# add parameters to execute stored procedure in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have problems when I try to execute a powershell script

```
$UuidMalo=0x0A398A6ADC9BE94CAD6769A81A7A5062
$UuidBueno = 0xA66C97A21D6C2748BD7D7D865205293E

$SQLCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SQLCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$SQLCmd.CommandText = $SQLCmdString
$SQLCmd.Connection = $SQLConnection


$SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@contactUUID1",[system.data.SqlDbType]::Binary) 
$SQLCmd.Parameters['@contactUUID1'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input

$SQLCmd.Parameters['@contactUUID1'].value = $UuidMalo1
```

the result after execute the script is

```
Must specify a file system
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[].
"
At C:\Program Files\ca\PAM\scripts\mergeContacts.ps1:52 char:34
+ $Result = $SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery <<<< () | out-null
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

with convert method the system is not capable to convert it the input because is to big.

this is the datatype in SQL

[image]

how can I add the parameter without errors...?
Thanks

Comment: What is `$UuidMalo1`? Is that the same as` $UuidMalo`?

Comment: Sorry, yes is the same var.

Comment: Sorry if this is off the mark but it just looks like PowerShell is having a cast issue. What if you declared the variable like this `[byte[]]$UuidMalo=0x0A,0X39,0X8A,0X6A,0XDC,0X9B,0XE9,0X4C,0XAD,0X67,0X69,0XA8,0X1A,0X7A,0X50,0X62`

Answer (score -1):

I modified the code and it works! but some times the connect is a problem. thanks!

```
param(
[String]$UuidMalo, 
[String]$UuidBueno
)


clear; 





$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "server=XXXXX-08\XXXXX,1434;database=mdb;user=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX"
$SqlConnection.Open()

$sqlCommand=$sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120
$sqlCommand.CommandText="exec spCheckListContacts " + $UuidMalo+ ","+ $UuidBueno+ ""

$sqlReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
$SqlConnection.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
param(
[String]$UuidMalo, 
[String]$UuidBueno
)
clear; 
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=XXXXX-08\XXXXX,1434;database=mdb;user=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX"
$SqlConnection.Open()

$sqlCommand=$sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120
$sqlCommand.CommandText="exec spCheckListContacts " + $UuidMalo+ ","+ $UuidBueno+ ""

$sqlReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
$SqlConnection.close()


try this i thing in your case it will work
```